# R: Purposefully "Sabotaging" Functions

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, trigonometry

I am working in R. I am trying to optimize the following function I defined:

```
library(ParBayesianOptimization)

bayesian_function <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
    var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
    var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
    var_3 <- x1 + x4
    var_4 <- x3 + x4 -7
    goal_1 = sum(var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4)
    
    
    if (var_1 > 0.6 ) {
        goal_1 = 111111111111111111111111111 }
    else {
        goal_1 = sum(var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4)
    }
    
    return(c(goal_1))
    
}

FUNwrapper <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4) list(
    "Score"=bayesian_function(x1=x1,
                              x2=x2,
                              x3=x3,
                              x4=x4))

bounds <- list(x1 =c(20,40), x2 = c(30,45), x3 = c(10,20), x4 = c(10,50))


optObj <- bayesOpt(FUN = FUNwrapper, bounds = bounds , initPoints = 10 , acq = "ei" , iters.n = 2 , gsPoints = 25 )
```

In the above example, I wanted to add an "intermediate limitation" (i.e. constraint) that forbids "var_1" from being greater than 0.6 . Since there is no direct way to do this according to the documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ParBayesianOptimization/ParBayesianOptimization.pdf) , I tried to purposefully "sabotage" this function by assigning "goal_1" an extremely large and non-sensical value to throw the optimization off.

However, I don't think it worked:

```
#view final results:
getBestPars(optObj)
$x1
[1] 38.52704

$x2
[1] 39.71733

$x3
[1] 17.63423

$x4
[1] 41.00297
```

Looking at this:

```
var_1 = sin(x1 + x2) = sin (38 + 39) = sin(77) = 0.97
```

and `0.97 > 0.6` (constraint not respected)

Can someone please tell me if there are other ways to add such constraints?

Thanks

Comment: In your test the code, you used `sin(38 + 39)`, but the 'getBestPars' object uses `sin(38.52704 + 39.71733)`.  `sin(38.52704 + 39.71733) = 0.2911669` , which is less than your threshold of 0.6.

Comment: thank you for your reply! does this mean that my code is correct?

Comment: I would not say I am an expert on what you are doing, but you may look at `optObj[[7]]$Score` to see the impact of your threshold. I messed around a bit, and saw that if you drop the threshold to zero instead of 0.6,  then you see huge/crazy  numbers.  In our original example, though, there may not have been any values that hit the threshold (see `optObj[[4]]$initGrid`)